# Traverse an object tree using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

A country has a list of states. A state has a list of cities. Find the state which has a city with the zip code 11201.

How do I do this?

When I do

```
Country.States.SelectMany(
                           s => s.Cities.Where(c => c.Zip ==11201)
                         )
                          .Select(s => s);
```

What I get is the city and not the state.

Comment: I corrected your spelling of 'States'; perhaps that is what was causing the issue?

Comment: Many cities have more than one zip code. How is that reflected in your model? Also, Navy ships have zip codes but not states; do you care?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Country.States.Where(s => s.Cities.Any(c => c.Zip == 11201));
```

As pointed by Benjamin Gruenbaum, if you want to retrieve one state (not a list), replace `Where` by `FirstOrDefault`

```
Country.States.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Cities.Any(c => c.Zip == 11201));
```

Comment: +1 just note that OP asked for "the" state, you should replace Where with First

Comment: FYI - You're missing the closing parentheses on both examples.

Answer (score 6):

Just for color, another approach:

```
var foo = 
    from state in Country.States
    from city in state.Cities
    where city.Zip == 11201  // Hey, that's my zip code!
    select state;
var justTheOne = foo.FirstOrDefault();
```